# Find multiple matches in a column and Fetch details - based on Student ID from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to List out Date wise data with reference to Cell Value.
I am missing out basic function.
Tried below function, not exactly getting what I need.

```
=INDEX('Sep2022'!C:C,MATCH($B$4,'Sep2022'!B:B,0)) 
=VLOOKUP($B$4,'Sep2022'!B3:D200,2,0)
```

---

**Destination (Plain Text)**

| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Month | Sep2022 | (Sheet Name) |  |
| Student ID | 170 | < Search ID |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Expected Output |  |  |  |
| StudentID | Stud Name | Date | Total Hrs |
| 155 | Nicola | 16/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 17/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 19/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| 155 | Nicola | 20/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 21/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 22/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 23/09/2022 | 03:05 |
| 155 | Nicola | 24/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 25/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| 155 | Nicola | 26/09/2022 | 01:00 |

---

**Source (Plain Text)**

| Student Name | Student ID | Date | Total Hrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nicola | 155 | 16/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 17/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 19/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Nicola | 155 | 20/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 21/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 22/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 23/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Nicola | 155 | 24/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 25/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Nicola | 155 | 26/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| text |  |  |  |
| Allen | 170 | 16/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Allen | 170 | 17/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 19/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Allen | 170 | 20/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Allen | 170 | 21/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 22/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 23/09/2022 | 03:50 |
| Allen | 170 | 24/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 25/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 26/09/2022 | 01:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 16/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 17/09/2022 | 02:00 |
| Allen | 170 | 19/09/2022 | 03:50 |

---

[image: Destination Sheet]

[image: Source Sheet]

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Hi. You are trying to find multiple matches in a column. But based solely on the formulas included in your question, you are going about this the wrong way. There are probably many way to approach this, but a `query` is an obvious candidate. A single formula in cell B7 will provide the dates (Column C) and Hours (Column D). FWIW, you also include the month/Sheet name (Cell  B3); a combination of `indirect` and `address` would also enable you to include this in your formula, creating a dynamic lookup range. I'll post an answer when you respond to the requests by @TheMaster.

Comment: as per guideline I have removed the link to spreadsheets

Comment: @Tedinoz - Please help me out with dynamic lookup range as you suggested

Comment: Yes, but you haven't added a plain text table. Click the link in my first  comment. Try `=FILTER()` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to generate the information that you require. This answer uses a `QUERY`.

Enter this formula in cell A7 of the destination sheet:
`=query({indirect(address(1,1,4,true,B3)&":D")},"select Col1, Col2,Col3, Col4 where Col1 is not null and Col2 matches '"&B4&"'",1)`

**About a dynamic range**

- the range is: `{indirect(address(1,1,4,true,B3)&":D")}`

  - this combines `indirect` and `address` to generate the contents of an array literal
  - `address` includes the sheet name in cell B3 which dynamically creates a range based on sheet `Sep2022`. You could further finetune this by using "Data Validation" to make the sheet (and even the Student ID" drop down selections.

---

**Sample**

[[image: sample query]]

---